# Sorting lists within a list in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list `J` consisting of lists. I am trying to sort elements of each list in ascending order. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
J=[[10, 4, 7], [10, 4],[1,9,8]]
for i in range(0,len(J)):
    J[0].sort()
```

The current output is

```
[[4, 7, 10], [10, 4], [1, 9, 8]]
```

The expected output is

```
[[4, 7, 10], [4, 10], [1, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Close, but try: `J[i].sort()` inside the loop rather than `J[0].sort()`.

Comment: You are sorting `J[0]` i times.

Comment: Use the object directly in the loop to avoid this confusion: `for li in J: li.sort()`

Comment: Try, either `[sorted(l) for l in J]` or `[l for l in J if l.sort() is None]`. Check the following URL for more details: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: @RaviJoshi The second example is very non-idiomatic and confusing. List comprehensions should not be abused for a side effect

Comment: @DeepSpace: I agree. I wrote it only because OP is using the sort() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the range

```
J=[[10, 4, 7], [10, 4],[1,9,8]]
for i in J:
    i.sort()
print(J)
```

Output:

```
[[4, 7, 10], [4, 10], [1, 8, 9]]
```